# Tutorial/example on setting up authentication for users and groups

Tags: gun, gundb

As of today I've fired up the GunDB example setup and must say I am impressed!

**User authentication**

However, in order to fully use it for my app I would really like to have an example on how to setup user authentication with certificates.

It would be very handy to have a practical example which I can use to continue the integration of Gun in a future release of my app.

**Groups**

Next to that I would like to have the same example for implementing groups for these users and their groups (Yes I know of the existence of [this](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/Security,-Authentication,-Authorization) page but I am searching for a solid example on how to apply that approach using Gun in a more practical way).

**Testing the approach using usernames & passwords**

Thanks a lot in advance and by the way, I would still like to test-run the new authentication method using usernames and passwords however, I also agree that certificates using public and private keys should provide for a more secure environment.

Best regards,

Comment: This is a great question! I'm confused why people are downvoting questions about security, groups, permissions, accounts, etc. maybe it is the NSA saying they don't want end-to-end encryption?!? Will try to answer this later, just got back from Sweden and swamped.

Comment: I agree, this is a great question (upvoted)